# glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml is not a valid domain (no domain.xml)

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, debian, eclipse-kepler

I am a newbie starting with **Java EE** and **GlassFish**, in **GNU/Linux Debian 7**, using **Eclipse Kepler** as IDE.

I have a problem when I try to install a new server in Eclipse. The steps I follow are:

- Click on Eclipse's link "No server are available. Click this link to
  create a new server..." on Servers tab.
- Select Glassfish>Glassfish 4.0 and click on next button.
- Select JDK and Glassfish Server Directory, then click on next button
  once more.
- Then an error message is appeared on the top of the context window:

  "***/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml is not a valid domain (no domain.xml)***"

http://oi43.tinypic.com/eivakp.jpg

I do not have much experience, specially in GNU/Linux but this is for auto-educational purpose, so I will be glad if your are so kind to help me to solve this situation :S

Any doubt I will try to clear it as soon as posible.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Are you sure the instance of Glassfish you're pointing to was properly installed and works correctly outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I notice the server is running at http://localhost:8080/ and I can admin at http://localhost:4848/. Any other way to know if is it working outside Eclipse? :S

Comment: That mean that it's more OK than Eclipse seems to suggest :).  Does `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists and it is not empty. Could it be about permission on domain1 or config folder?

Comment: Could be, as I assume you're executing Eclipse as your user, and GF was probably installed to run as root, or under a dedicated user.

Comment: That is right. I gave permission to my user in /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains, then I created a new domain with my user and finally I could perfectly create a new server in Eclipse. Than you very much!!! :)